# Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, admob, firebase-admob

In My flutter app google Ad is not loading in android app but works in ios.
I am using both AdMob and Firebase Database and i am using Macbook pro M1 and anroid emulator is downloaded from(https://github.com/741g/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases/tag/0.1). I am getting following error. One time loaded after some time its not loading. i restarted emulator.

**Error Log**

```
✓ Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
    Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58954/IMxJrHvKw0s=/ws
    Syncing files to device Android SDK built for arm64...
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    ****E/DynamiteModule( 7635): Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found****
    I/WebViewFactory( 7635): Loading com.android.webview version 83.0.4103.120 (code 410412053)
    D/nativeloader( 7635): classloader namespace configured for unbundled product apk. library_path=/product/app/webview/lib/arm64:/product/app/webview/webview.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/product/lib64:/system/product/lib64
    I/com.example.com( 7635): Waiting for a blocking GC ClassLinker
    I/com.example.com( 7635): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ClassLinker on ClassLinker for 7.565ms
    I/cr_LibraryLoader( 7635): Loaded native library version number "83.0.4103.120"
    I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder( 7635): Flushed 3 samples from 3 histograms.
    I/cr_VariationsUtils( 7635): Requesting new seed from IVariationsSeedServer
    W/com.example.com( 7635): Accessing hidden method Landroid/media/AudioManager;->getOutputLatency(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
    D/HostConnection( 7635): createUnique: call
    D/HostConnection( 7635): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7b216f9110, tid 7755
    W/cr_media( 7635): Requires BLUETOOTH permission
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    D/HostConnection( 7635): HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan ANDROID_EMU_deferred_vulkan_commands ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_null_optional_strings ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_create_resources_with_requirements ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_ignored_handles ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_free_memory_sync ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_shader_float16_int8 ANDROID_EMU_vulkan_async_queue_submit GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_host_side_tracing ANDROID_EMU_async_frame_commands ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
    W/Chrome_InProcGp( 7635): type=1400 audit(0.0:928): avc: denied { create } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tclass=vsock_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.com
    D/EGL_emulation( 7635): eglCreateContext: 0x7b31726d30: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
    D/EGL_emulation( 7635): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7b31726d30: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7ac177ec18) (first time)
    W/Chrome_InProcGp( 7635): type=1400 audit(0.0:929): avc: denied { create } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tclass=vsock_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.com
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:16.253778 | Catcher | FINE] Using debug config
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:16.270505 | Catcher | WARNING] Screenshots path is empty. Screenshots won't work.
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:16.280954 | Catcher | FINE] Catcher configured successfully.
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.025932 | Catcher | INFO] Setup localization lazily!
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.095563 | DiscordHandler | INFO] Sending request to Discord server...
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.099199 | DiscordHandler | INFO] Sending request to Discord server...
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.756470 | DiscordHandler | INFO] Server responded with code: 204 and message: No Content
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.756650 | Catcher | INFO] Report result: true
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.790840 | DiscordHandler | INFO] Server responded with code: 204 and message: No Content
    I/flutter ( 7635): [2021-05-16 12:15:19.792818 | Catcher | INFO] Report result: true
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    **E/DynamiteModule( 7635): Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found**
    I/Ads     ( 7635): Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("0C722C5BD4C3702E3B9AC5D6D2F52F51") to get test ads on this device.
    **E/DynamiteModule( 7635): Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found**
    I/DynamiteModule( 7635): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:204204100 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0
    I/DynamiteModule( 7635): Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): Google Play services is missing.
    W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
    D/zzfc    ( 7635): File /data/user/0/com.example.com/cache/1608138930680.dex not found. No need for deletion
    **E/DynamiteModule( 7635): Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found**
    I/DynamiteModule( 7635): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:204204100 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0
    I/DynamiteModule( 7635): Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite
    W/Ads     ( 7635): #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    W/Ads     ( 7635): com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazl: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazj.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:3)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzarl.zzn(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:22)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzarl.getVersion(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:31)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddx.zzatj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddw.call(Unknown Source:2)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeaj.zzbab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:5)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:8)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeah.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:11)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazu.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:4)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazt.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:4)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdyl.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:5)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddx.zzasy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:6)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfl.zzs(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:7)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqu.zzali(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:12)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqu.zzalj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:13)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbou.zzala(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:34)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbou.zzalb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:54)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdje.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:71)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:26)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:13)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:123)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:15)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:20)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterBannerAd.load(FlutterBannerAd.java:86)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.java:266)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
    W/Ads     ( 7635): Caused by: com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$LoadingException: Failed to instantiate module class: com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:260)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazj.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:1)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  ... 35 more
    W/Ads     ( 7635): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.ads.omid.DynamiteOmid" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~XTOLiYep8dZhgoF0J8AZXg==/com.example.com-hDko_XnXqo17zlbMET3Bkg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~XTOLiYep8dZhgoF0J8AZXg==/com.example.com-hDko_XnXqo17zlbMET3Bkg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~XTOLiYep8dZhgoF0J8AZXg==/com.example.com-hDko_XnXqo17zlbMET3Bkg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.instantiate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.3.0:257)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  ... 36 more
    W/Ads     ( 7635): #007 Could not call remote method. @28
    W/Ads     ( 7635): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdst.getVersion()' on a null object reference
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzarl.getVersion(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:32)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddx.zzatj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:10)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddw.call(Unknown Source:2)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeaj.zzbab(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:5)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdzs.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:8)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzeah.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:11)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazu.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:4)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzazt.execute(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:4)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdyl.zze(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:5)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzddx.zzasy(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:6)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdfl.zzs(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:7)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqu.zzali(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:12)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbqu.zzalj(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:13)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbou.zzala(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:34)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzbou.zzalb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:54)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzdje.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:71)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zzg(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:26)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzcxw.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads@@19.7.0:13)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzzm.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:123)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:15)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@19.7.0:20)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.FlutterBannerAd.load(FlutterBannerAd.java:86)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugins.googlemobileads.GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.onMethodCall(GoogleMobileAdsPlugin.java:266)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:818)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:335)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:183)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    W/Ads     ( 7635):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
    **E/DynamiteModule( 7635): Failed to load IDynamiteLoader from GmsCore: Application package com.google.android.gms not found**
    W/PlatformVersion( 7635): Build version must be at least 6301457 to support R in gmscore
    I/Ads     ( 7635): Ad failed to load : 0
    I/flutter ( 7635): Ad failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 0, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: Internal error.)
    D/EGL_emulation( 7635): eglMakeCurrent: 0x7b31716db0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x7ac1723298) (first time)
    W/Gralloc4( 7635): allocator 3.x is not supported
    W/com.example.com( 7635): type=1400 audit(0.0:936): avc: denied { create } for scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c123,c256,c512,c768 tclass=vsock_socket permissive=0 app=com.example.com
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.com"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 30
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // Lottie
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.0.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Flutter doctor**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-arm, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.0.6 at /Users/mak/Desktop/Dev/flutter
    • Framework revision 1d9032c7e1 (2 weeks ago), 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
    • Engine revision 05e680e202
    • Dart version 2.12.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/mak/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/mak/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • Android SDK built for arm64 (mobile) • emulator-5554                        • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile)           • 2F371B4A-6E20-4ECF-8DE1-06FB8266FCD8 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                         • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The plugin that you're using seems to need Google Play Services as mentioned in the logs: `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil( 7635): com.example.com requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.`

To solve this issue, you can either create an AVD instance with Google Play Services or run the app on a physical Android devices that has Play Services.